# What function do I use to remove a certain from a list with indexing in Python?

Tags: python

So I was trying to remove a certain line in a list as demonstrated below

`list = ('1','2','3','4','5')`

I was trying to do something along the lines of

`list.remove[0]`

to remove '1' but that doesn't work, how do I go about this?

Comment: Here `list` is a **tuple**. *tuple* has no method `remove`.

Comment: Don't edit original question. Original question had tuple, now it is modified to list.

Comment: @MoShaikG Your edit changed the code in the question. This is unhelpful.

Answer (score 0):

To delete an element in a python list based on index:

```
aList = ['1','2','3','4','5']
index_to_remove = 0
del aList[index_to_remove]
```

Answer (score 0):

Better use the pop function to remove the elements by using the index number

```
list = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
list.pop(0)
print(list)
```

the output is:

```
[2,3,4,5,6]
```

Answer (score -1):

Use slicing, instead of using remove.

```
L = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
L = L[1:]
print(L)
```